# Working of C code when same variable is defined with different data type

Tags: c

I unknowingly named a variable twice but with different data type. It missed the compilation error as one is in `main()` and other is in `while()` loop of `main()`.

So I made a code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t>0)
    {
        double t;
        scanf("%lf",&t);
        printf("%lf\n",t);
        t--;
    }

return 0;
}
```

And here I notice that the program never ends! For any input value of `double t` either a negative or positive or zero, `while()` loop never gets terminated.

Can anyone care to explain why is this happening? How does the while loop get terminated there?

Comment: This is a nice question.  But I hope it is purely academic for you now.  That is, I hope you have just re-named of the `t`-variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it yourself. You have two variables named `t` with different scope.

The `double t` you declared has the scope of the block that executes inside of the while loop. The conditional in the while loop uses the `t` that is declared in the scope surrounding the while loop (the `int t`) which is never modified (because the loop hides `t` and modifies the double t) and so it never reaches 0.

Here are some points about scope of variables in C:

- blocks inherit all global variables
- variables declared inside a block are only valid inside the block
- blocks can be nested
- a nested block inherits the variables from the outer block,
- variables may be declared in a nested block to hide variables in the outer block (such as in your case)

**EDIT**

As @pmg suggested, here are a couple of extra points:

- a hidden variable cannot be accessed at all, except through use of pointers created when it was still visible
- although strictly speaking, hiding variables is not an error, it's almost never a good thing and most compilers will issue warnings when a variable is hidden!

Comment: +1 I'd had that a 'hidden' variable cannot be accessed at all, except through use of pointers created when it was still visible.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone care to explain why is this happening?

There are two variables in your program called t. One is an `int`, at the scope of main, and one is a `double`, in the scope of the while loop. Inside the while loop the double t is hiding the int t, and your scanf is setting the double t.

> How does the while loop get terminated there?

The program can't be terminated from inside the while loop as written.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(t>0)//int t;
{
    {
        double t;
        scanf("%lf",&t);
        printf("%lf\n",t);
    }
    t--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the statement `t--` is executed, it refers to the (`double t`) variable declared earlier in the same block, so your `int t` in the outer block scope, which is shadowed by the `double t`, never gets decremented.

Comment: What if I give the double value of `t` as 0 or negative? It already does not accept to the condition of while loop, so the loop should break?

Comment: no matter what you give to t, because you have a scanf function following, the assigned value will be overwritten.